# Eclipse OSX Keyboard shortcuts find/replace

Tags: eclipse, macos, keyboard-shortcuts

Been using Eclipse for years in Windows and when I do a Find/Replace I use keyboard combinations like alt+d for and alt+n for "Replace next"/"Find next". On Mac there doesn't seem to be a way to do this quickly by keyboard. I have to Tab around to the button I want which is generally slower than using the mouse. How can have a direct keyboard shortcut to do this?

Comment: I don't think Mac OS supports keyboard mnemonics -- at least it's not a common feature in Mac OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mnemonics are discouraged: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Java/Conceptual/Java14Development/07-NativePlatformIntegration/NativePlatformIntegration.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001909-212166

I hate it, too.

Comment: I upvoted because the info is useful. NOT because I am (in the least) pleased about it.  Apple apparently seems perfectly happy to do carpal tunnel to us.  using the mouse excessively is a hazard.